# VS Code on Mac doesn't have merge conflict acceptance tools?

Tags: visual-studio-code, merge-conflict-resolution

According to the documentation, VS Code should have a merge conflict review that allows you to accept the merges:

[image]

However, I can't seem to access this functionality. If I open the file with the merge conflict, I only get a split view, which is nice, but I don't get any way to accept or reject changes and fix merge conflicts:

[image]

This is all I can see. How can I activate the view where I can accept or reject changes?